# My Android project won't use VPN

Tags: android, json, vpn, android-volley

I have a simple app that tries to access an API from a remote server. For testing, I need to use a VPN in order to access it since it is blocked in my current location. When using the browser on the phone, I can get the JSON response I need but when I run my app, It doesn't seem to use my VPN because the JSON response is not the same. I'm using the built in VPN of my test device which can be found in the settings. Any ideas about this? I'm using volley for request.